# Lineage feature in Cloudera Navigator

Tags: cloudera, data-lineage, cloudera-navigator

Does Lineage work in the Enterprise trial version of Cloudera?

I see the lineage tab but i dont get to see the lineage of the hive table which i derived from another hive table.
Unfortunately, this information is also not very clear from the Cloudera documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Lineage does work in the Enterprise trial version, but the lineage has to be clear to the navigator.

Which means: if a table is derived from another table, and there are no "drop table" at the end of the command. If you have to have a "drop table", put it at the start of the process.